# Why duplicated results query with cypher neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am implementing the example database Movies en Neo4j. I already search something about duplicated rows but I still have doubts

I am using **XOR**. I am getting the

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r]-(p:Person)
WHERE m.title STARTS WITH 'The' 
XOR (m.released = 1999 OR m.released = 2003)
RETURN m.title, m.released
So, my result is
```

[image]

As you can see, there are duplicated rows, I don't understand why there are doing that and the number of duplicated results is according to what?

> I know that DISTINCT removes duplicated. But I am interested in understanding why the query duplicated the results and the number of duplicated is according to what?.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are matching

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r]-(p:Person)
```

So the movie title will be returned for each person in the movie, so if there are 4 people in the movie, you will get four movie titles back. You can remove duplicates by matching only the movie

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
```

Comment: Sure, I got in deep for the results and I saw there were more relationships and the number of the repetitions matched with the relationships.

Answer (score 1):

As Tomaz said, it is returning a row for every :Person that has a relationship to :Movie. If you concluded your query with just `RETURN m` and viewed the results, you probably would only see non-duplicated nodes appear. Otherwise, you can conclude the query with `RETURN DISTINCT m` to ensure that non-duplicated results are returned.